# NServiceBus 4.03 Distributor puts 30 messages into storage queue for one message in the control queue

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor, nservicebus4

When the worker starts it drops a message into the control q and then when i start the distributor, it picks up the message from Control Q and puts **30** messages into the storage q. Any clue why???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that the worker reported it had 30 free threads and the msmq storage implementation for worker availability in the distributor stores each of those as a single message.

Comment: yep **<TransportConfig MaximumConcurrencyLevel="30" MaxRetries="0"/>**, the _MaximumConcurrencyLevel_ are the threads. It would be nice to create separate properties for concurrency level and FLR